# constructor Service.Service() is not applicable

Tags: java

I have a class with objects

```
public class Service {

    private Integer vlan;
    private String desc;
    private String vrf;
    private String address;
    private String JR;
    public Service() {
    }
    public Service(Integer vlan, String desc, String vrf, String address, String JR) {
        this.vlan = vlan;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.vrf = vrf;
        this.address = address;;
        this.JR = JR;
    }
    public Service(Integer vlan) {
        this.vlan=vlan;
    }
```

and I want add to listArray
the data that they are in excel file

```
try {
    Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("Taza-BLR.xls"));
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
    for(int i=1;i<sheet.getRows();i++)
    {
        liste.add(new Service(sheet.getCell(7, i).getContents()));
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
```

So they tell me this error:

```
constructor Service.Service(Integer) is not applicable
  (actual argument String cannot be converted to Integer by method invocation conversion)
```

How can I resolve this problem?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer.parseInt(String)` as this:

```
liste.add(new Service(Integer.parseInt(sheet.getCell(7, i).getContents())));
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Nooo they give me error also: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:504)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)

Comment: Then you are not recovering an integer :S. Try to debug or print which value are you recovering. If you receive that exception that means that the String you are getting cannot be parsed to an Integer.

Comment: if i can don't display the first column of title it will be good because all of data are integer so the title it's just string so i think this is why it gives me error but how can i eliminate the title

Comment: for(int i=3;i<sheet.getRows();i++) 
            {
                System.out.print(sheet.getCell(7,i).getContents());

Answer (score 0):

I assume your getContents return a String object. And your constructor expect an "Integer" object. Search the forum StackOverFlow itself, or look at API [Integer.valueOf(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) to convert String to Integer.

You should change the code to

```
 liste.add(new Service(Integer.valueOf(sheet.getCell(7, i).getContents())));
```

Comment: it gives me the title of cellule and the lines : the title is ID Vlan aso this result gives me : ID Vlan212821292130

Comment: for(int i=3;i<sheet.getRows();i++) 
            {
                System.out.print(sheet.getCell(7,i).getContents()); okey that's good it gives me just the numbers  but when i write that it gives me errors uff liste.add(new Service(Integer.parseInt(sheet.getCell(7, i).getContents())));

Comment: but in cellule in Exce file i have integers data just the title it's string what can i do now ??

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the cell content is returned as a String. If you know for sure you'll find an integer in there, you can parse it out of that String like this:

```
String contents = sheet.getCell(7, i).getContents();
try {
    Integer value = Integer.valueOf(contents);
    liste.add(new Service(value));
catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {}
```

Comment: it gives me the title of cellule and the lines : the title is ID Vlan aso this result gives me : ID Vlan212821292130

Comment: How could that be an `Integer` then ?

Comment: but in cellule in Exce file i have integers data just the title it's string what can i do now ??

Comment: Okey it works now really im sorry to disturb you and i understand now the problem thank you